# Apply input.button CSS on a submit button without changing CSS?

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a ton of system generated CSS rules which apply to `input.button`. Their structure is like this:

```
input.button {
    /* CSS properties here */
}
```

I have a form submit button, which is defined like this:

```
<input id="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
```

I want to apply all `input.button` CSS on this `submitBtn` too, but without having to manually modify all original CSS (to also apply it for `submitBtn`), or by manually duplicating all CSS rules for `input.button` for `submitBtn`

So is there a way to directly utilize the CSS meant for `input.button`, and apply it for a submit button, **without changing/adding/modifying/deleting any CSS code** ?

Answer (score 1):

If you can change in css then change

```
input[type=submit]
```

If you can change in button then change

```
<input id="submitBtn" type="submit" class="button" value="Subscribe" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an attribute selector - `input[type=button]`.

Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors for more info.

Comment: I think your solution is similar to the other ones too, that I add `input[type=button]` in the CSS .. Unfortunately I cannot do that .. Thats the whole point of this question ..

Comment: Ah I see you edited your question - it wasn't clear in the original version. I don't think there is a way to do what you are after. You will have to give ever button a class of `button` or go change the css.

Answer (score 0):

```
input.button, #submitBtn {
    /* CSS properties here */
}
```

Comment: Cannot accept this because this requires directly modifying the CSS rules .. I cannot do that because they are like 15-25 or so, and they are system generated ..

Comment: @Ahmad Can you modify the HTML? Can you just add the "button" class to the submit button?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one....

For all three kinds of buttons:

```
button,input[type="button"],input[type="submit"] 
{ 
 //Line
}
```

Comment: Cannot accept this because this requires directly modifying the CSS rules .. I cannot do that because they are like 15-25 or so, and they are system generated ..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way only for **this button**

```
input[value="Subscribe"]{
 // here css style 
}
```